# Why the width of the HTML tag is smaller when served with a local server?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an empty (boilerplate html) `index.html` file with the following style:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If I serve the file from a server or open it directly from the hard drive, the width for the `html` tag is correct.

> file:///var/www/html/foobar1/index.html
>
> somedomain.com/index.html

width is **1280px**

If I start an Apache server or a Python server and visit the containing folder

> localhost/foobar1

width is **1163.636px**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].clientWidth
1163
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].offsetWidth
1164
```

Chrome `Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit)` running in Ubuntu `14.04.2`

This does not happen in Firefox. Is this a bug or am I missing a config of some kind?

The `index.html`: https://gist.github.com/givanse/ed850a0983d53c766d2f

So far I have:

- cleared all browser data
- disabled all the extensions

no dice

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error using exactly the same version of Chrome. I'm serving an HTML file through Apache and opening the same file locally, and the width is the same in each as reported by the `offsetWidth` and `clientWidth` properties. How are you measuring the width?

Comment: I'm inspecting the tag with the Chrome dev tools, the panel that shows computed properties and the UI for the box model. I updated the question with a link to the complete file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a culprit, ended up doing:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome
rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome/
```

And reinstall.